# NSDateFormatter problems between versions 10.4 and 10.5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, date

I'm creating an app that needs to run on 10.4 and above. Having a date string that is formatted properly is crucial. When I run my program in 10.5 debug everything is good; I get a date which is exactly how I want it:

```
 Jul 13, 2010 16
```

the 16 being the hour without the minutes, which I specifically need. Then when I run it in 10.4 I get this:

```
 07/13/10
```

My code to produce this date looks like this:

```
  NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH"];

  NSDate *newNow = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:newNow];
```

After reading some relevant documentation (link below), it seems like 10.4 has a unique way to to format that is different then 10.3, 10.5 and 10.6. To quote the link:

"The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode standard (this reference is to version tr35-6 for Mac OS X v10.5; for Mac OS X v10.4 use version tr35-4)."

I've gone through the documentation and it seems like my Unicode format is okay, but I'm still getting this odd result.

Any help?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the formatter behavior to `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4` using `+[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:]` or `-[NSDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:]`.

EDIT: my reasoning is based on the comment in the NSDateFormatter overview saying:

> By default, on Mac OS X v10.4
>   instances of NSDateFormatter have the
>   same behavior as they did on Mac OS X
>   versions 10.0 to 10.3. On Mac OS X
>   v10.5 and later, NSDateFormatter
>   defaults to the 10.4+ behavior.

Comment: That totally did the trick. For anyone else that has to try this I would add that you need to place // [NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4]; before everything else, including the alloc and init stuff.